# '[value]' not setting control value in reactive form Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following scenario:

```
<input #physicalAddress1 type="text" formControlName="PhysicalAddressLine1" />

<tfg-toggle #physicalAsPostal 
            formControlName="PhysicalAsPostal" 
            [onText]="'Yes'" 
            [offText]="'No'"></tfg-toggle>

<input type="text" 
       formControlName="PostalAddressLine1" 
       [value]="physicalAsPostal.value === true ? physicalAddress1.value : ''" />
```

As can be seen from above, a `template reference variable` is set on 'PhysicalAddressLine1', and if 'PhysicalAsPostal' is selected (true), the value from 'PhysicalAddressLine1' should be duplicated/copied into 'PostalAddressLine1' `[value]`.

On the UI, this works as expected, but as soon as the form is submitted, the value for 'PostalAddressLine1' is empty.

Here is how I retrieve the values from the submitted form:

```
let provider: Provider = Object.assign({}, this.providerFormGroup.value);
console.log(provider.PostalAddressLine1); // Empty string: ""
```

Not sure why I am experiencing this behavior.  What should I do differently?

Comment: Share your ts file

Comment: What is `tfg-toggle`? Does it implement `ControlValueAccessor`? If it doesn't, you won't be able to do anything by passing `formControlName="PostalAddressLine1"` to it.

Comment: Toggle behaves like a checkbox, either true or false, irrelevant to this question.  Like I have mentioned, I can see the PostalAddressLine1 input field being populated with the data from the PhysicalAddressLine1 input field, but when I submit the form, the PostalAddressLine1 formcontrol control's value is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monsterthie, you can not use formControlName and [value] together. You need change directy PhysicalAddressLine1.controls.PostalAddressLine1.value. You can use values changes in .ts after create the form. Some like: (*)I imagine a component that implements OnInit and OnDestroy

```
alive=true; //<--declare a variable
ngOnInit(){
  this.form=this.fb.group(...)
  this.form.controls.PhysicalAddressLine1.valueChanges
     .pipe(takeWhile(()=>this.alive))
     .subscribe(res=>{
       this.form.controls.PostalAddressLine1.setValue(res?res:'')
     })
}
ngOnDestroy()
{
   this.alive=false;
}
```

NOTE: I include a typical construction to remove the subscription when component is destroyed

Comment: I was hoping I did not have to do this. Thanks.